# Trouble creating an empty array as a default value instead of NULL in prisma

Tags: prisma, supabase

I am trying to create an empty array as a default value instead of null.

Here is my schema:

```
model User {
  id       String    @id @default(uuid())
  name     String
  comments Comment[]
  image    String

  @@unique([id, name])
}

model Comment {
  id           String    @id @default(uuid())
  message      String
  createdAt    DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime? @default(now())
  user         User      @relation(fields: [userId, userName], references: [id, name], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId       String
  userName     String
  parent       Comment?  @relation("ParentChild", fields: [parentId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  children     Comment[] @relation("ParentChild")
  parentId     String?
  likes        String[]  @default([])
  dislikes     String[]  @default([])
  commentScore Int?      @default(0)
  replyingTo   String?
  replies      String[]  @default([])
}
```

The issue is with the likes, dislikes and replies fields, which show in my supabase db as NULL instead of the empty array.  I have tried rerunning `npx prisma generate` and well as `npx prisma db push`.This isn't a huge problem as I can still manually add what I need to but it's still bugging me so I figured I'd ask and hopefully someone can share some insight.

Thanks.